# .htaccess RewriteRule Change Directory To Query String 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my .htaccess file, which is mean to convert a directory to a query string parameter:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^g/XXXXXXXXXX-WINEGIFTS1$ g/index.php?u=XXXXXXXXXX-WINEGIFTS [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^g/(.*)$ g/index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So, http://example.com/g/SOMETEXT should get rewritten as http://example.com/g/index.php?u=SOMETEXT

As it stands, it works fine.

However, if I uncomment out the commented line, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

That line is meant to rewrite one specific URL, http://example.com/g/XXXXXXXXXX-WINEGIFTS1, as http://example.com/g/index.php?u=XXXXXXXXXX-WINEGIFTS

The weird thing is that I have the exact same code running on a different domain, on a different server, and it works fine.

Any thoughts on what's causing this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you uncomment the first rule then the second rule becomes unconditional and it matches **/g/index.php**  twice and rewrites to inself causing an endless rewrite loop .

You can use the following

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
##--Skip the all rules bellow if an existent file/dir is requested--##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#########
 RewriteRule ^g/XXXXXXXXXX-WINEGIFTS1$ g/index.php?u=XXXXXXXXXX-WINEGIFTS [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^g/(.*)$ g/index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you're saying about the loop, I think (although I thought the L attribute would prevent that), but I still get the 500 error with the above code.

Comment: @Mark The L flag doesnt stop  rule processing ,it just tells the engine to exit the current rewrite cycle and forwords the request for 2nd phase of processing